# Joining shapes in Affinity Designer

Tags: vector, affinity-designer

I am teaching myself the very basics of design using [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/) - and I haven't been able to figure out how to create a single shape from multiple vectors.

For instance, if I am creating a basic outline of a car and need to start and stop lines - when I use the `join lines tool` it doesn't join two unrelated lines together - rather it completes the "circle" (path) of one line only.

If I use the `join shapes tool` it completes all the unconnected lines, and fills in those spaces too - so I lose the shape I am after.

AD's help index is not very helpful to someone with my near non-existent skills - so I'd be thrilled if someone on this forum can help.

Comment: Hi Amanda, not sure if any of our regulars are familiar with Affinity, I've never even heard of it but it does look like something to check out. I also edited your question a little so it wasn't as "bulky" to read.

Comment: It does look neat! *"You can use pressure from a stylus – or velocity – as a controller to produce beautiful, clean strokes that are fully editable"* - nice, definitely going to check it out! By Serif... huh, I thought they went bust...

Answer (score 23):

You can indeed join two separate nodes from unrelated vector lines.

Do this by :

1. Select both lines using the Move Tool.
2. Using the Node Tool select both end nodes you want to join (hold down Shift to select them both).
3. Choose 'Join Curves' from the Action section of the Node context toolbar.

Comment: Welcome to GD!  We look forward to more questions in regards to Affinity but please be aware we require full disclosure of your affiliation with Affinity and it must be edited within your profile.  For better understanding of how the site works please review our [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Consider it done :)

Comment: Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't ;)

Comment: ... and when it doesn't, export the shapes together as PDF and load them back, will work

Answer (score 7):

With the node tool (hit A) shift-select both curves you want to join together.  Then, in the context toolbar at the top there are a bunch of buttons labelled "Action" - they look like this:
[image]

the fourth button along from the left is "Join Curves" (you'll see that when you hover over it) and clicking on that will join the two separate lines together.  Hope that's what you're after...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the compound. E.g. I was trying to create an object out of 2 shapes where the inner shape forms a hole. So I used the complement compound (The square with the circle and the intersection is missing).

For other stuff you might need the other operations for forming compounds.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please (just add the image and delete the deading `!`, one with more rep can activate it for you)?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify a bit, I think you mean this: Say you had a line with 3 nodes, a,b, and c, with a and c being the endpoint of the nodes. You wish to attach another another line with two nodes d and e. You wish to connect the nodes b and e.

As of right now, I can't seem to find functionality of the program where it attaches two unrelated lines that AREN'T endpoints of each line.

I think the Pen module Affinity designed assumes you are always wanting to produce an endpoint to endpoint shape. But unfortunately, when creating lambda shapes, asterisks, x's, f's, $'s, etc. you're going to run into some issues. I would love to see the ability of the pen to create complex shapes that are much less dependent on endpoint snapping.